# Serialization : How does JVM keep track of which all object have already been written to the stream

Tags: java, serialization

In the following program.

```
public class SerialExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.txt"));

        Car c = new Car(20);

        os.writeObject(c);

        c.setSpeed(30);

        os.writeObject(c);

        os.close();



        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("out.txt"));

        Car d = (Car)in.readObject();
        Car e = (Car)in.readObject();

        System.out.println(d.getSpeed() + "   " + e.getSpeed());

        in.close();
    }
}


class Car implements Serializable{
    private int speed;

    Car(){
        speed = 1;
    }

    Car(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed){
        this.speed = speed;
    }

}
```

The output of the above program is 
20 20.

That means when it is writing the same object the second time instead of writing the object it has written a handler.

My doubt is how does JVM keep track of which all object have already been written to the stream?

Comment: You can call `ObjectOutputStream.reset();` to make it forget all the written objects, which will cause that all the objects are written again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) class is responsible for handling this logic.

From the Java [Object Serialization FAQ](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#handle):

> The ObjectOutputStream class keeps track of each object it serializes
>   and sends only the handle if the object is written into the stream a
>   subsequent time. This is the way it deals with graphs of objects. The
>   corresponding ObjectInputStream keeps track of all of the objects it
>   has created and their handles so when the handle is seen again it can
>   return the same object. Both output and input streams keep this state
>   until they are freed.